# How to Remove # tag from url MEAN STACK

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, elasticsearch, meanjs

Hi i am using Mean stack for a Web application problem is the url containing #!

something like

```
 http://host:3000/#!/signup
```

I want the urls like

```
  http://host:3000/signup
```

How to do this.

Comment: they look same to me...!

Comment: if you're looking to remove the # sign try this
http://scotch.io/quick-tips/pretty-urls-in-angularjs-removing-the-hashtag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `$routeProvider`, use the HTML5 History API:

> $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

**Setting  For Relative Links:**

To link around your application using relative links, you will need to set a `<base>` in the `<head>` of your document.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <base href="/">
</head>
```

You can read about this in detail here: [Pretty URLs in AngularJS: Removing the #](http://scotch.io/quick-tips/pretty-urls-in-angularjs-removing-the-hashtag)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Enable HTML5 for `$locationProvider`, by adding following code

```
 $locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');
```